# Authenticate the Swashbuckle Swagger UI page for ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Does anybody know of a way to authenticate the Swagger UI page generated by the Swashbuckle NuGet package in a Web API application ? To be clear, I've already figured out how to authenticate the requests the Swagger UI page makes to the API. There's plenty around on Google about how to do that. What I want is to authenticate the user before they can even make it to the Swagger UI test client page in my Web API application. This is for a Web API application hosted in Azure using Azure Active Directory for authentication.

Comment: The easiest way would be to place the documentation pages under forms security. If your users already have AD accounts then that would be it, with one line added to the web config.

Comment: @RossBush Can you please show me that line ? Because as far as I'm aware, Forms security is very different than the Azure AD accounts which are authenticated via the Owin pipeline and are in no way integrated with Forms security.

Comment: I deleted the answer since you are looking for something more specific to tie into the swashbuckler swagger's httprequesthandlers.